# how to generate python strings with formatter variables that my contain apostrophes and/or quotes?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, web-scraping, sqlite

I have built a function to build sqlite commands in python 3.6 from text I scrape from websites. The length of the sql command varies depending on the text that was retrieved.

```
def build_sql_stmnt(row, table, col_val):
    """builds an sql_stmnt to query fencers_db1.sqlite
       input: 
            row -- string, row data wanted
            table -- string, table to query
            col_val -- tuple with column/value pairs
                  Ex1: (('column', value),)
                  Ex2: (('column1', value1), ('column2', value2))
        returns: sql_stmnt -- string to be used as c.execute SELECT argument
    """    


    string = ''
    countdown = len(col_val)

    for pair in col_val: 
        if countdown > 1:
            string = string + ("""{} = '{}' AND """.format(pair[0], pair[1]))
        else:
            string = string + ("""{} = '{}'""".format(pair[0], pair[1]))

        countdown -= 1

    sql_stmnt = """SELECT {rw} FROM {tbl} WHERE {s};""".format(
                rw = row,
                tbl = table,
                s = string)
     return sql_stmnt
```

I have resorted to triple quotes to define the strings above when I discovered that the text I scrape may include double quotes ("). Now, I have found that the text I scrape can also include apostrophes ('). When I run the function when col_val includes an apostrophe ("Fencers' Club") I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: near "Club": syntax error
```

The following returns the same error:

```
 if countdown > 1:
        string = string + ("""{} = \'{}\' AND """.format(p0, p1))
    else:
        string = string + ("""{} = \'{}\'""".format(p0, p1))

    countdown -= 1
```

Is there a better way to build an sql statement, or is there a way to generate strings with variables that may contain double quotes and/or apostrophes?

Comment: If you're scraping my site, and I have a column value like [`Robert'); DROP TABLE Importantstuff; --`](https://xkcd.com/327/) that tricks your code into deleting a whole table worth of data… is that something that would matter to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to build SQL statements by manually quoting things like this.

Almost always, the answer is to use SQL parameters. For cases like this, where even the table name is a dynamic string, you can't do that.

That's why most SQL libraries come with a function to quote or escape values to be inserted manually. Unfortunately, `sqlite3` is the main exception to that.

So, you have to write your own escaping function. As [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) explain:

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes (`'`). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL.

So:

```
def esc(s):
    return "'{}'".format(s.replace("'", "''"))
```

And now, you have to manually call it everywhere you have a string value:

```
string = string + ("""{} = '{}' AND """.format(pair[0], esc(pair[1])))
```

---

As a side note, you seem to be a bit confused about the difference between string literals and string values. All of these literals create an identical format string:

```
'{} = \'{}\' AND '
"{} = '{}' AND "
"""{} = '{}' AND """
```

So, when you call `format` on that string, it doesn't matter which one of them you started with. The `{}` bits just get replaced with the contents of the `format` args. If there are quotes in those args, `format` will just copy the quotes in, and nothing you can do to the string literal for the format string will change that. You need to fix the args, as string values.

---

Anyway, on further reflection, you *can* probably use SQL parameters here—not in place of `format`, as you'd usually want to, but *in addition to it*. And then you *don't* have to worry about manually escaping things, because the strings you're `format`ting in don't need to be escaped, just the column values that.

What you need to do is build up a string plus a list. For example:

```
whereparams, whereargs = []
for col, val in col_val:
    whereparams.append('{} = ?'.format(name))
    whereargs.append(val)
whereclause = ', '.join(whereparams)
# ...
sql = '''SELECT {rw} FROM {tbl} WHERE {wc}'''.format(
    rw=row, tbl=table, wc=whereclause)
```

You can execute the query (whether now, or somewhere in the future) like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql, whereargs)
```

… knowing that the sequence `whereargs` has exactly the arguments that go with the `?` values in the SQL statement, in the same order.

Comment: The first option works when I remove the single-quotes from the string:  `def esc(s):
    return "{}".format(s.replace("'", "''"))`